# How to handle getOrCreateIfAbsent inside a DDD aggregate?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

I have a situation in my requirements I would like to see if someone has a strong opinion about it.

The project I'm working on requires that, given a Customer, once the Customer adds a Product to a Cart, if the Cart is not present, the Cart has to be created. At the moment, the aggregate is the Customer and it contains the Cart that contains the Product. Because this system is kind of a side one that supports the real e-commerce project, the creation of the Customer and the Cart is taken for granted once an "AddProductCommand" is received. In that situation, both Customer and Cart have to be created if they are not there already.

My current implementation creates the Customer at the application service if it doesn't exist. Once created, I pass the `AddProductRequest` using `customer.addProduct(addProductRequest)`. `AddProductRequest` contains the Cart id and the Product id. The problem comes here. Once in the Customer aggregate, if the Cart is not there, I have to create it. So basically, I don't have an `addCart` in customer with a Cart entity that I call first to then call `addProduct`. I need to create the Cart if it's not there from inside the Customer aggregate and then add the Product to it. And to do this, I don't create any factory as I don't want to have a static method that complicates testing and I can't just create a new factory inside the aggregate either. I just create the Cart entity using the new operator in a protected method that I override when testing to verify what I'm doing there.

So my question is, is this a valid approach? In my head, to add a Product to a Cart, the Cart should be added first to the Customer and fail if it's not there. To do it this way I would need to add logic to the application service where first I would ask the Customer if he has a Cart with that id, create it otherwise, and add it to Customer before adding the Product. I could add a domain service that is given this request but then I would need to inject the factory to create the Cart into it, when I've read in several places that a domain service shouldn't be injected any factory, that should be the work of the application service.

I could do it that way but the project will get more complicated in the future as there will be yet another layer where a Product could be added a list of Vouchers having to also create Customer, Cart and Product if they are not there when the `AddVoucherCommand` is consumed. In this situation, if I don't want to create the entities inside the model, I would need to check at the application/domain service whether each aggregate or entity has the necessary entity inside it, which I don't think is very DDD friendly, or just keep doing what I'm doing at the moment. This is, each aggregate/entity is in charge of create the necessary entity before calling the `addXXXX` method on it.

Some simplified code to explain what I'm doing at the moment and what I'm going to have to do in the future:

```
public class CustomerService {
    public void addVoucher(AddVoucherRequest addVoucherRequest) {
        Customer customer = customerRepo.load(customerId);
        customer.addVoucher(addVoucherRequest);
        customerRepo.save(customer);
    }
}

public class Customer() {
    public void addVoucher(AddVoucherRequest addVoucherRequest) {
        Cart cart = getOrCreateIfAbsent(addVoucherRequest.getCartId());
        cart.addVoucher(addProductRequest);
    }
    private Cart getOrCreateIfAbsent(long cartId){
        Optional<Cart> cart = carts.stream().filter(cart -> cart.getId() == cartId).findFirst();
        return cart.orElseGet(() -> {
             Cart newCart = createCart(cartId);
             carts.add(newCart);
             return newCart;
        }
     }
     protected Cart createCart(long cartId) {
         return new Cart(cartId);
     }
}
public class Cart() {
     public void addVoucher(AddVoucherRequest addVoucherRequest) {
         Product product = getOrCreateIfAbsent(addVoucherRequest.getProductId());
         product.addVoucher(addVoucherRequest);
     }
     private void getOrCreateIfAbsent(long productId) {
         Optional<Product> product = products.stream().filter(product -> product.getId() == productId).findFirst();
        return product.orElseGet(() -> {
             Product newProduct = createProduct(productId);
             products.add(newProduct );
             return newProduct ;
        }
     }
     protected Product createProduct(long productId) {
         return new Product(productId);
     }
 }
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: But then I would be creating two aggregates in the same transaction which is not recommended. Besides, this domain is rather simple as it´s not the full blown e-commerce app but a subset of it. I think the Cart in this case belongs to the Client as it cannot exist without it. And it wouldn't solve then the problem when I had to add the Voucher either.

Comment: The system will require to check, for every Customer, which ones have some specific Vouchers at some specific moments in time. Once found, those Customers will be updated for a week so they cannot get some treatments they get applied. Carts are saved, not deleted and the Products and Vouchers as well. This system has to run fast so everything is kept in memory and once an event is sent, all Customers that are eligible and have specific Vouchers have to be notified. So basically, I need to now some state for each Client and their Carts, Products and Vouchers.

Comment: `creating two aggregates in the same transaction which is not recommended` : which 2 aggregates are you referring to ? Cart and... Customer ? Why would a Customer be created at that point ? Shouldn't it exist already ?

Comment: Also, *creating* two Aggregates in the same transaction is not exactly as bad as *updating* two Aggregates. By definition, there is no concurrent access to things that are being created.

Comment: In the current approach,there is only one aggregate, Customer.2 aggregates was a suggestion from guillaume31 but i was explaining before,i consider everything inside Customer as I have an invariant in Customer that depends on the data contained in Cart, Product and later in Voucher.Customer may not have yet been created as the requirements say that,for a command requesting to add a Product to a Cart, the Cart may not have been created yet,in which case it has to be created.It's this creation my main problem as at the moment is the Cart that creates it with the data in the request

Comment: How can there be an invariant on `Customer` that depends on data contained in `Cart`, `Product`, `Voucher` ? Is a new `Customer` created each time a user shops ? Something seems wrong with your ubiquitous language here, there might be a breakthrough waiting to be discovered.

Comment: If the user is not yet in this system (as mentioned,this is a small system dependent on the real e-commerce system) it has to be created on the fly.its only data is its id and the list of carts it may have and a timestamp of when he was issued a kind of promotional alert.this alert is triggered based on its Products and later on on its Vouchers inside the Carts.this is why a Customer needs to know about Carts,Products and Vouchers.the e-commerce system is not going to be modified as it's legacy so this system is developed as a help system.it may be another way of doing it but i don't see it

Comment: Got it. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing to wait for a Customer to order something to create him/her in the new system rather than importing all Customers from the legacy system upfront is a purely technical decision, it has nothing to do with your domain IMO.

Therefore, it shouldn't affect the way you design your domain objects in any way - as I understand it, `getOrCreateIfAbsent()` should be a behavior in some kind of application service, not in one of your entities.

Comment: So,according to that,if given the case where for a given Customer not yet created i get an addVoucherRequest, should i then create all the relevant entities at the application service?my problem here is that,if the Customer is not there yet,I can create it at the application layer with a factory.But what if the part missing is a Product in a Cart?as you mentioned,not having all the data upfront is a technical decission that i can't overcome,i need to work with these requirements and the system uses async messages that in this case could lead to lost messages.an exception thrown is no option

Comment: You can't conjure up data out of thin air, everything has to be in `AddVoucherRequest`. If you have all the data, you can successively create every entity you need in the service. That being said, I find the concept of a new voucher relating to an old product in an old shopping cart totally weird.

Comment: I also recommend you ask another question (preferably on http://programmers.stackexchange.com) about strategies to hydrate data in that "supporting system", regardless of DDD. I have a gut feeling that you chose a subpar approach, although I don't have much experience with this kind of problem to back it up. In any case, it's difficult to tell without a better idea of what that system is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks.yes,definitively i have all the info in the request.otherwise i wouldn't be able to create the entities.it felt weird to me to create the Cart,Product and Voucher for every request but after thinking about it,there is no other way.the id of each entity will be used to first find the entity inside Customer and add first the new one if not found.i agree the requirements are weird but this is what i got